# Pull values from Shopify response array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

This has to be the stupidest question ever, but how do I pull values out of this Shopify API response?

```
orders = [#<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x007fb987a4f900 @attributes={"id"=>4141918472, "email"=>"fake@fakemail.com", "created_at"=>"2016-09-28T14:12:49-05:00", "total_price"=>"109.99", "order_number"=>1001, "billing_address"=>#<ShopifyAPI::BillingAddress:0x007fb987a4e410 @attributes={"first_name"=>"John", "address1"=>"111 Fake St", "phone"=>nil, "city"=>"Los Angeles", "zip"=>"90210", "province"=>"California", "country"=>"United States", "last_name"=>"Doe", "address2"=>"", "company"=>nil, "latitude"=>34.0670499, "longitude"=>-118.2714165, "name"=>"John Doe", "country_code"=>"US", "province_code"=>"CA"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>, #<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x007fb987a46b98 @attributes={"id"=>4141925128, "email"=>"aljdsfjalidsfnadf123132@yahoo.com", "created_at"=>"2016-09-28T14:14:25-05:00", "total_price"=>"309.97", "order_number"=>1002, "billing_address"=>#<ShopifyAPI::BillingAddress:0x007fb987a456f8 @attributes={"first_name"=>"afd", "address1"=>"744 Fake", "phone"=>nil, "city"=>"Chicago", "zip"=>"60021", "province"=>"Illinois", "country"=>"United States", "last_name"=>"adsfasd", "address2"=>"", "company"=>nil, "latitude"=>42.1976923, "longitude"=>-88.2120315, "name"=>"afd adsfasd", "country_code"=>"US", "province_code"=>"IL"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]
```

I used orders.class and it says it's an array. Is this an array of a hash? I can use .to_json but orders[0].to_json['email'] returns email. I've tried things like orders[0][1] and orders[0]['id']. But I cant get anything to work. What am I missing?

Comment: in the console or debugger, type `orders.first` and see what you get.

Comment: Tried that as well, it returns #<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x007fd66abf38d8>

Comment: Try `orders.first.email`. The API should map the attributes directly to methods. So `orders.first.email/order_number/billing_address` etc. probably works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do (depending on whether Shopify defines `attr_reader` on `attributes` instance variable) either

```
orders.first.attributes
```

or

```
order.first.instance_variable_get(:@attributes)
```

To get all orders' data:

```
orders.map(&:attributes)
# or, if above is not working, but it should
orders.map {|order| order.instance_variable_get(:@attributes) }
```

## Edit

As per @Casper's comment, it would be logical to be able to do the following if API provides readers to attributes:

```
 orders.first.email # or any other attribute
```

Comment: I think the API maps the attributes to methods directly. So `orders.first.email` should do it. Not 100% sure on this though, but seems silly if it didn't do that.

Comment: @Casper indeed it would make total sense (I'm not familiar with shopify's API either)